# How to cacth timeout connection to a EJB from standalone application

Tags: timeout, client, ejb

I want to know if it's possible to know and catch when a remote call to a EJB is not answering in a time period that I can set. I use to call the EJB a standalone client application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Check out this URL. it might be helpful

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/network_timeouts/